# Wordpress Photo Gallery not displaying - the_content

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am diving into creating my first WordPress Theme and I am finding myself pretty stuck on something.  The website is a one-page website, but I am loading the content for each "section" through the WordPress "pages" CMS.  So here's what I have:

```
<?php
$page_id = 2;
$page_data = get_page( $page_id );
echo '<h2>'. $page_data->post_title .'</h2>';// echo the title
echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
?>
```

This has worked great for everything so far.  Grab the page id, get the title from that page and go get the_content.  Does the_content not know what a WP photo gallery is?  It knows what a standalone image is, because if I click "Insert image into post" it shows up fine.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you should rather use [setup_postdata( $page_data )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata); and then use the_title() and the_content().

Comment: Is that a pretty standard thing to do instead of using the_title() and the_content() ?  Just trying to figure out the difference for my own understanding.  Thanks!

Comment: Its recommended. There are work arounds but it is always best to use the wp's function to do the job.